# How to fix arxiv primary category

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv

When we submitted a paper, the arxiv recommended math.PR as primary category. I think I have declined that. But somehow it got changed anyway. Now the paper is about to be announced, how to change it?

We have tried:

1.Replacement. This operation does not allow one to change the primary category.

2.Cross list. Only allow adding category.

3.Withdraw. It should work, but will generate too many announcement (withdraw and resubmission).

Comment: I guess this is caused by an ArXiv moderator.